# What exactly is Mother Superious Tasha Lem of Papal Mainframe?

Tags: doctor-who

> Clara: She hasn't aged much.
>   The Doctor: No, she's against ageing.

This is a conversation from *The Time of The Doctor* episode of *Doctor Who (2005)*.

Also, Dalek nanobots didn't seem to fully work on Tasha. She was able to gain control over her consciousness.

What is Tasha? What does it mean that she is against ageing?

Comment: [Related thread](http://www.quora.com/Doctor-Who-TV-series/Is-Mother-Superious-Tasha-Lem-a-developed-version-of-River-Song) on Quora that may be of interest to you.  Unfortunately it's all guesswork.

Comment: Nothing to indicate she isn't just some bog standard human with high will power, like the rest of the church.

Comment: @cde Are you saying, one can stop ageing process with high will?

Comment: @SS, surgery, medicine, science, prayer. The high will power part was specifically towards the Dalek control part of your question. i. e. the doctor telling her to fight it.

Answer (score 1):

1. The Doctor says she's against aging. That might be The Doctor assuming she hasn't aged because of some technology of her era. But the point to note here is that **she has been infected with Dalek nanobots**. This could have slowed/halted her aging process. None of the crew seemed to have aged over the span of 300 years either.

   - In the Dalek Asylum, even dead bodies were in their flesh & skeleton state. Even Harvey[Clara's crewmate] hadn't aged much. Admitted the cold environment was also a factor in preserving their bodies. However it seems conceivable that this was also a minor side effect of Dalek nanobots.
2. She was able to gain control over the nanobots by sheer will power.

> DOCTOR: Right, get us back to the Tardis. Can you do that?
>
> TASHA:
>   Yeah, but quickly, the Dalek inside me is waking.
>
> DOCTOR: Fight it.
>
> TASHA: I can't.

This indicates that she was consciously fighting the nanobots, & they were regaining control over her.

- This is doable, which is also seen in Asylum of Daleks, where The Doctor urges Amy to fight it, & also is able to retain his own persona even after being exposed to the nanobots.

Answer (score 0):

Is a human, an exceptional one but a human.
The not ageing thing might be a technology issue. The Eleventh Doctor might have done something like this because in "The Impossible Astronaut" the Doctor has 907, and then he is 1103, and that would be 196 years (without ageing), but in Trenzalore he lives there for 300 years (and ageing a lot).
But the thing is that the origin of The Church of the Papal Mainframe is human (there where some Anglicans in the Church, also the structure of the Church is the same as in Catholicism, but with all the military things).
And the thing about the Dalek-conversion, might be the same as when Craig stopped the Ciber-conversion process, with willpower and, let's say "love".